# Can we use multiple fonts on the basis of different language to create overlay text using intervention library?

Tags: php, laravel, intervention

I'm using **Intervention** library to write overlay text on an image.
This works perfect if the text provided is of one language(say English)

I need to write overlay text in multiple languages depending on the input given(the input can be in any language).

Here is my code base for generating the above.

```
public static function generateTextOverImage($image, $text)
{
    $img = Image::make($image->getContent());
    $extension = 'jpg';
    $centerX = 25;
    $centerY = 210;
    $text = str_replace('<br>', "\n", html_entity_decode($message)) ;
    $lines = explode("\n", wordwrap($text, 21));
    $currentLineVIndex = $centerY;

    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        $img->text($line, $centerX, $currentLineVIndex, function ($font) use ($fontSize) {
            $font->file(public_path('fonts/LucidaGrande.ttf'));
            $font->size(18);
            $font->color('#fdf6e3');
        });

    }
    $encoded = $img->encode($extension);
    return $encoded;
}
```

As the text can be in different languages(One or more language at a time). The expected text over image in broken.
It works fine for english language only.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

#### Update

is there any font which support multiple languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it at my own. Posting my solution here, may be it will help someone having similar problem.

The Solution was, using a **unicode** font (Arial Unicode MS) which supports different fonts.

Following is the solution

```
public static function generateTextOverImage($image, $text)
{
    $img = Image::make($image->getContent());
    $extension = 'jpg';
    $centerX = 25;
    $centerY = 210;
    $text = str_replace('<br>', "\n", html_entity_decode($message)) ;
    $lines = explode("\n", wordwrap($text, 21));
    $currentLineVIndex = $centerY;

    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        $img->text($line, $centerX, $currentLineVIndex, function ($font) use ($fontSize) {
            $font->file(public_path('fonts/arial-unicode-ms/arial-uni.ttf'));
            $font->size(18);
            $font->color('#fdf6e3');
        });

    }
    $encoded = $img->encode($extension);
    return $encoded;
}
```